# Not allowed to reference UIApplication in frameworks?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, ios-frameworks, ios-extensions

I wrap some common tasks in functions in my framework. Some of these tasks need to do something to `UIApplication.shareApplication()` such as:

```
public func scheduleNotification(application: UIApplication, indentifier: String) {
    var notification = UILocalNotification()
    ....
    application.scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
}
```

Originally, I was using `UIApplication.shareApplication()` directly in my function, but pulled it up to the parameters since I was getting a warning in Xcode. The warning remains though so what exactly does this error trying to tell me?

`warning: linking against dylib not safe for use in application extensions`

Comment: iOS Extensions like keyboards and today/share extensions can't use `UIApplication`. So it is unsafe for use. Unless you want to use this framework in an iOS extension, or are going to provide it to people who might want to do so, you're fine. AFNetworking has (or had at one point) a special preprocessor define that made it safe to use with app extensions if the user typed `#define AF_APP_EXTENSIONS`, you could look into that to find out how to get rid of this warning.

Comment: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/2119 this may be helpful.

Comment: Hello =) Have you found a solution? i have the same problem with Xcode 7 GM. What i basically want to do is to perform Local Notifications from watch. My idea was to create framework from which i could perform func that will call UILocalNotification creation.

Comment: Use some kind of communication (e.g. delegate pattern) between your framework and your device target so you can do all the logic in your framework and the app related things in your app code.